# Call every element one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo-10

I have 3 paragraphs here. The problem is that they are displaying at the same time.
What I wanted is they will auto show and then hide one at a time.

Scenario: 
First paragraph // show then hide 
Sec paragraph // next show then hide 
Third paragraph // next show then hide

```
           if(p_name != "" && l_name != "" && t_name !="")
            {
                session.rpc('/custom/custom', 
                {
                    p_name: p_name,
                }).then(function () 
                {   
                    
                    $("p.one").addClass("show").hide(5000); 
                }); 

                
                session.rpc('/cus/cus', 
                {
                    l_name : l_name,
                }).then(function () 
                {
                    $("p.two").addClass("show").hide(5000);
                }); 

                session.rpc('/cuz/cuz', 
                {
                    t_name : t_name,
                }).then(function () 
                {
                    $("p.three").addClass("show").hide(5000);
                });
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what you are looking for

```js
if (p_name != "" && l_name != "" && t_name != "") {
  session.rpc('/custom/custom', {
    p_name: p_name,
  }).then(function() {
    $("p.one").addClass("show").hide(5000);

    session.rpc('/cus/cus', {
      l_name: l_name,
    }).then(function() {
      $("p.two").addClass("show").hide(5000);

      session.rpc('/cuz/cuz', {
        t_name: t_name,
      }).then(function() {
        $("p.three").addClass("show").hide(5000);
      });
    });
  });
}
```